# Why is Result.map in Kotlin behaving diferently for Unit types?

Tags: kotlin

I am confused about the following two Kotlin code snippets:

A:

```
val r: Result<Unit> = Result.success(Unit).map { Result.success(Unit) }
```

B:

```
val r: Result<Int> = Result.success(Unit).map { Result.success(1) }
```

Snippet A compiles while snippet B does not compile.

Can someone explain why snippet A works with the Kotlin type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to return a Result from the `map` lambda. You're supposed to return a value that will be wrapped in a Result. That's why your code B fails. It would succeed with just `map { 1 }`.

Code A succeeds because when Kotlin expects a lambda to return Unit, it implicitly returns Unit regardless of what the last line of code in the lambda is. If it didn't do this, any lambda that has no return value would have to end with a line that says Unit. In the same way, any function with no explicit return value has an implicit return type of Unit, but the compiler does not require you to explicitly write `return Unit` at the end of your functions.

Comment: great explanation, it can be 'proven' by deleting the type declaration on variable in case A. The compiler then infers the returned type to be `Result<Result<Unit>>`

Comment: Thanks! "Code A succeeds because when Kotlin expects a lambda to return Unit, it implicitly returns Unit regardless of what the last line of code in the lambda is. " This was the piece of information that I was missing.